# Laravel/ VueJS project - Console Error not showing where the error is located

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm finding VueJs extremely difficult to troubleshoot in my laravel/Vuejs project. I was working on my project and I was making a feature that consist of a few vue components, everything seems to work like I expect, but suddenly I noticed there is an error message in the console - 'props must be strings when using array syntax'. As you can see the error does not give any information about where the error is located (no line number in a certain component). I can not seem to pin poin the issue and all of my components are receiving props like so - `props: ["someprops"]`, like I've always done. So I'm not sure what the error is suggesting. Can someone help me figure out what is going on and possibly adjust my settings in laravel mix to see more useful errors? As my project is growing I'm finding that the errors are becoming increasingly difficult to find. I'm not so much as interested in fixing this particular error as I am on how to trouble shoot all errors going forward [image: not useful error message]

Comment: Can you add some part of the code where you think the error might be?

Comment: @Amaarrockz, I'm not sure where the issue is exactly, I made about 7 components during the time the issue came about. But my questions is how to find where the issues are... not so much how to fix this particular issue. I was wondering if there was some kind of setting I'm missing to get a better idea on how to find errors. I should also note that when I console log something, it doesn't tell me what line or in what component the console log is in. the console log will show up in the console but it will say like  - line 22883. I want to say line 7 in compoent <info-box>...

Comment: Somewhere in your code you must be having mix of string and Object in your prop array. Best way to trace it, is put a breakpoint in app.js:245392

Then reload the page, wait for it to hit the breakpoint. Then in Call Stack you can check for the origin of the issue.

Comment: you can do one thing, add `console.log` inside `mounted` of each components. In that way you ll be able to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.sourceMaps();
```

This will show you where the error is located in the uncompiled code.